# How to login with woocommerce login api in android

Tags: android, authentication, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am a newbie to this approach. I am integrating woocommerce into my android app. Through woocommerce products api i am able to list all the products. But i am not getting how to login into android app using woocommerce login api.

I am listing the products like this.

Get https://your-host-name/wc-api/v1/products?&consumer_key=******&consumer_secret=*******

I am able to list all the products successfully from this. How can I implement the login approach?